# Enable/Disable RelativeLayout view(s) on Spinner select

Tags: java, xml, spinner

I have three Relativelayout views set up in my XML one after eachother, in my onCreate method I have initialised all three views and setEnabled() to false. Then I have set up a Spinner and I want to enable each view when each respective button is clicked. Is there a way to do this? So far I have (on my Spinner):

```
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Quantity")) {
                calSelectInt = 1;
                calSeek.setEnabled(true);
                calWeight.setEnabled(false);
                calFlour.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Dough Weight")) {
                calSelectInt = 2;
                calSeek.setEnabled(false);
                calWeight.setEnabled(true);
                calFlour.setEnabled(false);
            } else if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Flour Weight")) {
                calSelectInt = 3;
                calSeek.setEnabled(false);
                calWeight.setEnabled(false);
                calFlour.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
```

The cal___ represents each view. The calSelectInt is an attempt to set an Integer for each and call in another method when each Integer is read.

As a result when run, all three views are viewed, any ideas? Why isn't setEnabled working? Or is my code poorly thought out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to setVisibility(View.GONE) and (View.VISIBLE) instead of setEnabled(boolean). Strange, that method didn't seem to work for me in the past with other things but hey ho.